# Упаковка ресурсов в CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

В Visual Studio при разработке проектов на `winapi` есть возможность упаковки ресурсов через файл `.rc`. Как сделать что то подобное в `CMake` (`CLion`)?


Сам `CLion` я запускаю на Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: А компилятор какой? MSVC или MinGW? Или вы хотите, чтобы это работало на любом компиляторе?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat На вижле? MSVC.

Comment: Я имею в виду, каким компилятором вы собираете через CMake/CLion. Тоже MSVC?

Comment: Компилятор - g++

Comment: Как минимум с MinGW-w64 (у вас скорее всего такой GCC) в комплекте идет программа `windres`, которая из `.rc` делает `.res` файлы, которые потом линкуются в программу. А вот как запускать windres из CMake - не знаю.

Comment: Ах да. CLion я запускаю на Ubuntu 18.04. Вообще у меня есть проект, который я хочу собирать под windows и под linux. Соответственно VS у меня на винде а CLion на линуксе.

Comment: Ни в cmake, ни в clion ничего подобного нет, так как они используют наличиствующие в системе компиляторы и прочие инструменты, а сами ничего не собирают. Соответственно и использование .rc файлов происходит как обычно. А `.rc` - это ресурсный скрипт для платформы windows. Зачем он понадобился вам на убунте? Вы собираетесь делать кросс-компиляцию на windows? Если да, то укажите, какой у вас тулчейн и как вы его используете в cmake.

Comment: Я пишу программу, которую в итоге хочу скомпилировать и на windows и на linux. Сам rc файл мне безразличен. Я хочу найти способ упаковать вместе с файлами кода файлы изображений, которые позже буду отрисовывать в самой программе.

Comment: Тулчейн -- https://imgur.com/THH0Qyr

Comment: На линуксе придется поплясать с бубном. см [embed image inside program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422123/sdl-embed-image-inside-program-executable/18422431#18422431). Посредством `objcopy` создаете из файлов объектный файл с экспортом затем линкуете его в свое приложение. ЗЫ как именно выглядит тулчейн можно посмотреть в соотв. файле cmake. clion в этом плане совсем бесполезен.

Comment: [Вот еще](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/) про способ, который предлагает VTT.

Comment: Хорошо. Я думаю, этот способ можно написать в качестве ответа.